# Best way to group similar actions using Rails Routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I want to be able to group similar actions under one controller to keep things neat and clean.

For example, if I have a `Game` model, and I currently have:

```
resources :games do
  get 'schedule/previous', to: "Games#previous"
  get 'schedule/upcoming', to: "Games#upcoming"
  get 'schedule/calendar', to: "Games#calendar"
end
```

These obviously get more and more unweildy, especially because I have a bunch of other actions in my `GamesController`. How can I move these to a new controller (or otherwise organize them more cleanly)?

If possible I'd like to put the new "`Schedule`" controller under `app/controllers/games/schedule_controller.rb` or something like that.

I tried to do this using namespaces, scopes, and resources (and most of the combinations of two of those) and couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this as you want

**First modify the routes**

routes.rb

```
resources :games do
  get 'schedule/previous', to: "games/schedule#previous"
  get 'schedule/upcoming', to: "games/schedule#upcoming"
  get 'schedule/calendar', to: "games/schedule#calendar"
end
```

app/controllers/games/schedule_controller.rb

```
class Games::ScheduleController < ApplicationController
  #Metods here
  def previous
  end

end
```

**Another option if you are using rails 4 is to use concerns. Its not necessary no modify routes.rb**

app/controllers/concerns/schedule.rb

```
module Schedule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  #Metods here
  def previous
  end
end
```

app/controllers/games_controller.rb

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  include Schedule
end
```